# IEEE 754 floating point - why does this work?

Tags: javascript, double, ieee-754

Given the following:

```
.1 + .2 === .3 // false
1 * .3 === .3 // true
```

...the former does not result in `0.3` because one or more of the operands cannot be exactly represented in IEEE 754 double-precision floating point, so the result is almost but not quite `0.3`.

Why does the latter return `true`. Is it because `0.3` happens to be exactly representable in IEEE 754 double-precision floating point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.3 is not exactly representable, but 1.0 is. Multiplication of any number by 1, under IEEE round-to-nearest rules, must return the original value, which is equal to itself.